# Tapering effect in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, matrix, geometry, transformation

I need to implement a tapering effect on a movie clip while keeping it aligned to some guide lines. For example, if my movie clip looks like this

[image]

after the transformation it should look like this

[image]

so that the **movie clip's shape stays symmetrical and the height doesn't change**. The length of the top edge stays the same. Also there would be nice to have control over the angle at both sides, but for a start I'd like it to be 45 degrees like on the image above.

What I've tried so far is this

```
var m3D:Matrix3D = new Matrix3D();
m3D.appendRotation(-45, Vector3D.X_AXIS);
myMC.transform.matrix3D = m3D;
```

I've played with it for a long time, adding translations back and forth but fruitless. This doesn't work either

```
var mcX:Number = myMC.x;
var mcY:Number = myMC.y;
var mcW:Number = myMC.width;
var mcH:Number = myMC.height;
m3D.appendTranslation(-(mcX + mcW/2), -mcY, 0);
m3D.appendRotation(-45, Vector3D.X_AXIS);
m3D.appendTranslation(mcX + mcW/2, mcY, 0);
```

I did find the [DistortImage](http://www.rubenswieringa.com/blog/distortimage) class but the license is for non-commercial use and it doesn't seem to work with movie clips natively. A [similar class](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?325592-AS2-AS3-Stretcher-and-DistortGrid-%28image-distortion%29) looked promising but the links to the source are dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash uses a simple frustum model with a viewpoint, projection plane, and `focal length`, which is the distance from the viewpoint to the projection plane.

[image]

There is also fieldOfView but it should be of no importance as its meaning appears to be overridden by focalLength.

The rectangular piece of graphics is located right on the projection plane so that the middle point of its top edge is located in the projection center. To achieve the effect, the rectangle is rotated by some `angle`.

[image]
[image]

The question is, what should be the values of `focal length` and `angle` so that `new height` and `new bottom width` satisfy some given values that are desired for the effect? Or speaking mathematically:

Given:

- a frustum with `focal length`
- a rectangle with its `width` and `height`, which is pinned to the projection plane (z=0) of so that the midpoint of the rectangle's top edge is located right in the projection center of the frustum
- the needed `new height` and `new bottom width` of the rectangle after it's rotated and projected onto the projection plane

Unknowns to be found and applied to the perspective projection in order to get the desired `new height` and `new bottom width`:

- the `focal length` of the frustum
- the `angle` of rotation

Grabbed a pencil, piece of paper, and Maple (math software) and solved it by myself.

```
var newBottomWidth:Number = 1000; // or any other value
var newHeight:Number = myMC.height; // or any other value

// the computational part
var oldWidth:Number = myMC.width;
var oldHeight:Number = myMC.height;
var eqRoot:Number = -Math.sqrt(newBottomWidth*newBottomWidth*oldHeight*oldHeight - newHeight*newHeight*oldWidth*oldWidth);
var focalLength:Number = Math.abs(eqRoot/(newBottomWidth - oldWidth));
var angle:Number = Math.atan2(eqRoot/(newBottomWidth*oldHeight), newHeight*oldWidth/(newBottomWidth*oldHeight));
var angleDeg:Number = angle*180/Math.PI;

myMC.parent.transform.perspectiveProjection = new PerspectiveProjection();
myMC.parent.transform.perspectiveProjection.projectionCenter = new Point(myMC.x + myMC.width/2, myMC.y);
myMC.parent.transform.perspectiveProjection.focalLength = focalLength;

var m3D:Matrix3D = new Matrix3D();
m3D.appendRotation(angleDeg, Vector3D.X_AXIS);
myMC.transform.matrix3D = m3D;
```

More information:

- [PerspectiveProjection - AS3](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/PerspectiveProjection.html)
- [Projecting 3D objects onto a 2D view](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS36223081-8938-4b45-BB89-F1F8B1A52E4E.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly add beforehand translation and then after-translation, say if the center point you select (around which rotation should be done) at (cx,cy), you add translation to `-cx,-cy` then rotate then translate backwards.

```
m3D.appendTranslation(-1*cx,-1*cy,0);
m3D.appendRotation(-45, Vector3D.X_AXIS);
m3D.appendTranslation(cx,cy,0);
```

Comment: Your MC is transformed around its own zero, thus you shouldn't use `mcX` or `mcY` in translation, only width and height.

Comment: Tried that too. Still get a non-symmetrical result shifted to the left.